# How to set up a Login Dialog in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, android-alertdialog

I was trying to add a login in my edit button. What I want to do is that, when a user selected an item to edit, then hits the edit button a pop-up will show asking for the person's username and password. I tried making a login dialog but I keep on failing.

Here is my code:

```
public void btn_edit_click(View v){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View prompt = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(prompt);
        final String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        final EditText user = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        final EditText pass = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        final TextView msg = (TextView) prompt.findViewById(R.id.login_error);
        final String password = pass.getText().toString();
        user.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME"));
        if(this.selected_website != null){
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {   
                    DBAdapter dbUser = new DBAdapter(PasswordActivity.this);
                    dbUser.open();
                    if(dbUser.Login(username, password))
                    {
                        show_add_layout();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg.setText("Username or Password is incorrect");
                    }
                }
                });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.show();  
                    }                   
                    else{
                        show_mesg("Please select item to edit.");
                    }
    }
```

When I click the OK button, it gives me the statement "Username or Password is incorrect". But I have typed the right username and password. Any help on this?

Comment: Please share your dbUser.Login(username, password); function code.

Comment: Where in the code are you comparing the user entered username and password with the ones on record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After an hour, I managed to solve my own problem. So I wanted to share this answer so if anyone would encounter such problem as I had a while ago, they can use this as a good reference.

What I did was, I tried using the code for my Login class. But I didn't ask for the username anymore. What I asked was only the password. But for the username, I get the Intent from the previous login. So it's like, you logged in with a username "john316" and your password is "123abc" and then you will be redirected to the main class. there you select an item in the listview, and when you click edit, a pop-up would show asking for your password for verification. BUT, any password won't work. It will call the password from the db and from the username you logged in(which is "john316") if it is right, you will be redirected to the edit class. If it is wrong, it will show you, "PASSWORD IS INCORRECT." and will block you from going to that page. To shorten this explanation, here is the code:

```
public void btn_edit_click(View v){
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View prompt = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(prompt);
    final String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
    final EditText pass = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    final TextView msg = (TextView) prompt.findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    if(this.selected_website != null){
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {   
                String password = pass.getText().toString();

                try{
                    if(username.equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME")) && password.length() > 0)
                    {
                        DBAdapter dbUser = new DBAdapter(PasswordActivity.this);
                        dbUser.open();

                        if(dbUser.Login(username, password))
                        {
                            show_add_layout();
                        }else{
                            msg.setText("Password is incorrect");
                        }
                        dbUser.close();
                    }

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PasswordActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            });

                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.show();  
                }                   
                else{
                    show_mesg("Please select item to edit.");
                }
}
```

And that's how it works. I thank those people who answered my question and gave me a little help. I hope this one's gotta help others too. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What happens when you rotate the screen? The current recommendations are to use dialog fragments. 2 years later, this answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not getting User Name correctlly like passwor , as you are using this.

```
  final String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
```

But you are inputting user name like password in your Dialog EditText filed for userEmail. You should use this to get inputted userName

```
final String username  = user.getText().toString();
```

Also you should validate User Name , Passowrd for null , empty before checking it in DB